# Pandas как посчитать для каждого часа значения за предыдущие семь часов

Tags: python, pandas

Добрый день! Есть DateTimeIndex. Как посчитать для каждого часа количество значений за последние семь часов, чтобы потом вклеить в другую таблицу с почасовым DateTimeIndex? И еще как для каждого часа посчитать отношение `значение этого часа / значение этого же часа`, но день назад?

[image: Исходный DateFrame]

Нужно посчитать для каждого часа количество state за последние 7 часов в отдельный DateFrame. И скажем вот у нас есть `2016-06-01 13:00` - за этот час было столько-то заказов, а есть `2016-06-30 13:00` - за это время было столько-то заказов. Как вывести отношение `заказы за этот час / заказы за этот же час предыдущего дня` по часам, то есть для 13:00, 14:00 и т.д. Тоже в отдельный датасет, предыдущие задачи решил при помощи resample, как эту задачу решить - не пойму.

Comment: а нельзя поподробнее? Что, где, на чем вы имеете... [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Михаил, спасибо за интерес, дополнил примером DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

Пример DataFrame'а:

```
In [22]: df = pd.DataFrame({'state':[True]*25,
    ...:                    'time':pd.date_range('2017-08-01 11:08',
    ...:                                         freq='31T', periods=25)})\
    ...:        .set_index('time')
    ...:

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
                     state
time
2017-08-01 11:08:00   True
2017-08-01 11:39:00   True
2017-08-01 12:10:00   True
2017-08-01 12:41:00   True
2017-08-01 13:12:00   True
2017-08-01 13:43:00   True
2017-08-01 14:14:00   True
2017-08-01 14:45:00   True
2017-08-01 15:16:00   True
2017-08-01 15:47:00   True
2017-08-01 16:18:00   True
2017-08-01 16:49:00   True
2017-08-01 17:20:00   True
2017-08-01 17:51:00   True
2017-08-01 18:22:00   True
2017-08-01 18:53:00   True
2017-08-01 19:24:00   True
2017-08-01 19:55:00   True
2017-08-01 20:26:00   True
2017-08-01 20:57:00   True
2017-08-01 21:28:00   True
2017-08-01 21:59:00   True
2017-08-01 22:30:00   True
2017-08-01 23:01:00   True
2017-08-01 23:32:00   True
```

Решение:

```
In [24]: df.resample('H').count().rolling('7H').sum().shift(freq='1H')
Out[24]:
                     state
time
2017-08-01 12:00:00    2.0
2017-08-01 13:00:00    4.0
2017-08-01 14:00:00    6.0
2017-08-01 15:00:00    8.0
2017-08-01 16:00:00   10.0
2017-08-01 17:00:00   12.0
2017-08-01 18:00:00   14.0
2017-08-01 19:00:00   14.0
2017-08-01 20:00:00   14.0
2017-08-01 21:00:00   14.0
2017-08-01 22:00:00   14.0
2017-08-01 23:00:00   13.0
2017-08-02 00:00:00   13.0
```

Comment: что-то считает, но странно, потому что df начинается с 13:08, и в принципе не может быть значений за последние 7мь часов, проверил сейчас диапазон  df['2016-06-01 00:00:00':'2016-06-01 13:08:03'] -- нет значений до 13:08. А у Вас он что-то записывает туда.:) Но я новичок, не знаю пока что такое rolling и не совсем понимаю синтаксис, но мне кажется, что это немного не то.

Comment: @SergeyPopov, попробуйте убрать 'min_periods'

Comment: все равно высчитывает для '2016-06-01 13:00:00' а не должен -- должно быть 0. А есть 2016-06-01 13:00:00  106.0  106.0  106.0

Comment: @SergeyPopov, вы можете привести в вопросе небольшой пример входных данных (в текстовом виде, чтобы можно было скопировать) и ожидаемый результат?

Comment: Вот данные: fm = pd.DataFrame([{
  'time': '2016-06-01 13:08:03',
  'driver': 'trompemile@feest.info',
  'rider': 'lefflergenoveva@spinka-nikolaus.info',
  'state': True,
}, {
  'time': '2016-06-01 14:00:00',
  'driver': 'emely65@haley.biz',
  'rider': 'jillwaters@hotmail.com',
  'state': True,
}]) У меня каждый час куча поездок. Мне нужно получить на каждый час количество поездок за последние семь часов. индекс 13:00 -- подсчет кол-ва значений с 7:00 по 13:00 часов включительно. и так на каждый час.

Comment: класс! Теперь почитаю как работает rolling и  shift. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Всегда рад помочь! Кстати у StackOverflow есть [отличная возможность сказать спасибо](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) ;-)

Comment: ,галочку поставил, на рейтинг вопроса влиять пока не могу.:)

Comment: @SergeyPopov, помимо галочки, Вы можете еще и проголосовать за ответ(именно ответ MaxU, а не вопрос) нажав на стрелочку вверх ;-)

Comment: @МихаилРебров, спасибо, но для этого необходимо иметь как минимум 15 балов репутации;)

Comment: @MaxU , понял) ...ну тут я уже помог чем смог)

Comment: @МихаилРебров, спасибо! :)